# How to go to parent class in Vim coc-java

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I’m using neoclide coc-java plugin  in my vim config.

https://github.com/neoclide/coc-java

Let’s say I have some interface and its implementation. I have opened implementation, my cursor is on implementation of a interface’s method and I want to go to the interface method.
How can I do it? There are ‘go to definition’ and so on but I still cannot find such functionality...
Is this possible?

I tried:

```
<Plug>(coc-declaration)
```

calling on implemented method with no luck:

```
Error on notification "jumpDeclaration": declaration provider not found for current buffer, your language server don't support it.
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @romainl. I read plugin's doc.
`coc` supports it, but not `coc-java` (or JLS). So the decision is to use `ctags` for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `con-java` does not support it (or LS).
So the decision is to use `ctags`...
I've created issue there:

https://github.com/neoclide/coc-java/issues/153

and will use `ctags`

Comment: It would be even better to use https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags